# How forces work during hammerthrow

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

I am not sure if I understand how forces work during hammerthrow. From my understanding athlete works with Fmuscle force on a ball and rotate it and a ball works with equal opposite force on an athlete causing rotation in a opposite direction. The mass of athlete is greater than the mass of ball so athlete rotates with ball in 1 direction(Fmuscle direction). Does it mean if ball would be heavier(more massive) than athlete, the athlete could not rotate it(even if strong enough to move it) ?
[image]

Comment: The athlete and the center of rotation are _not_ coincident. Hence the tension is _not_ perpendicular to motion and we have net positive power transfer of $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{v} \gt 0$

Comment: Make sure to be in a galilean frame of reference. The athlete frame is not (see @ja72 comment).